I'm installing Google Cloud BigQuery package, but I'm encountering vulnerabilities during corona scan
Hi I am looking for an advice.
I am installing the latest Google Cloud BigQuery python package but during corona scan(cisco product which is used to find vulnerabilities in docker container image) I was getting grpc vulnerabilites.
corona is detecting grpc 1.51.1(this is high vulnerabilites) in the paths:
usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyarrow/libarrow_flight.so.1400
usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-310- 
x86_64-linux-gnu.so

how to mitigate this issue or remove installing entirely 1.51.1
I tried to install grpcio  latest versions but I am still getting the issue.
getting the vulnerability CVE-2023-44487, CVE-2023-4785, 2023-33953

Why does this have the dockerfile tag?
